# Is it okay to include my connection in all request in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have 3 files. `db.js`, `app.js`, `commentController.js`.
I am including my connection in every request in my app so that I wont be repeating the code connection again and again. Is this a bad / unsecure practice? Is there a better/proper way to implement this?

**db.js**

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host     : 'host',
    user     : 'user',
    password : 'password',
    database : 'dbname'
});

exports.pool = pool;
```

**app.js**

```
const db = require('./db');

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.pool = db.pool;
  next();
});
```

**commentController.js**

```
exports.showComments = (req, res) => {
  req.pool.getConnection((err, conn) => {
    conn.query(`SELECT * FROM comments`, (err, results, fields) => {
      conn.release();
      if (err) throw err;

      res.render('comments', { results });
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Why doesn't `commentController.js` `require` the pool directly? Some form of DI? But I'd think there were better ways of doing DI...

Comment: I can see some benefit to this if you're planning on mocking the database interface for testing, but it's a long shot and there's better ways. I would require the pool directly, as TJ Crowder suggests

Comment: The main problem with what you're doing is that it "hides" a dependency which makes your route files less reusable.  And, since `db.pool` is not actually related to the `req` object, there's no legitimate programming reason that it should be stored there.  As Mark says in his answer, just `require()` in your db module in any module that needs it.  This states the dependency directly in your code which is the way to do things with node files. Yes, it seems like a little repeated code in each route file, but that's how you are explicit with dependencies and is the way to do things in node files.

Comment: And, even if you never intend to resuse any of your route files, this is a slippery slope.  One should learn the proper way to make modules as self-describing as possible and as stand-alone as possible and use those methods everywhere even when you don't initially intend to resuse the module.  Lots and lots of modules that end up getting reused later did not anticipate that when they were first written.  Following the design techniques for reusability is always a good practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your only reason for doing this is to avoid duplicating code, then I think it's a bad idea. People looking at your code (or you looking at your code in a year) aren't going to naturally expect a db connection to be a property of `req`. And you aren't saving yourself any trouble really.

Just `require()` the database pool in the file and use it.

**commentController.js**

```
const db = require('./db');
```

`require()` will return the same pool to all your modules.

It's also not clear why you are requesting a connection rather than using the pool (I'm making some assumptions about the lib you're using).

Normally you should be able to do:

```
const db = require('./db');

exports.showComments = (req, res) => {
    db.query(`SELECT * FROM comments`, (error, results, fields) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render('comments', { results });
    });
});
```

This saves the trouble of requesting and returning connections and just lets the pool do it's work.